# Indian Visa -- when does 180 days countdown start

Tags: visas, india, visa-expiration

I am in India currently with 10 years tourist visa. Which has limitation of 180 days.

I want to know when does 180 days countdown starts? From date my visa was issued or day I land in India?

Answer (score 7):

A 10-year visa allows multiple entries. Thus, the 180-day limitation refers to the duration of stay, which begins each time you arrive in India.

Comment: Also, note that due to COVID-19 situation, you can easily get extension online without even visiting FRRO - https://indianfrro.gov.in/eservices/home.jsp

Answer (score 2):

India allows maximum stay of 180 days on Tourist visa, from the date of entry, for a multiple entry visa.

Please refer to the link: https://www.in.ckgs.us/visa/tourist-visa

Please note, CKGS processes visa for India Gov at above website